# vscode: Is it possible to show an image inside a text buffer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

e.g. I write a markdown document and include a line like `[myimage](/mypath.jpg)` to see the image in a big size above or below this line.

When I'm writing markdown I regularly have to look at an embedded file. At the moment I have to use a split layout and switch my attention between the text buffer and the preview. That's slowing me down and distracting.

What I mean is a full size preview that can fill the whole width of the buffer and is permanently shown. This is offered by the emacs markdown-mode (see [this image](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode-guide/blob/master/manuscript/images/inline-images-on.png) with a command named "markdown-toggle-inline-images".). This is also available in sublime text e.g. via an add-on named [sublime_zk](https://github.com/renerocksai/sublime_zk#inline-local-image-display). This is possible in atom with add-ons like [preview-inline](https://atom.io/packages/preview-inline) or [inline markdown images](https://github.com/msafi/inline-markdown-images).

This would allow to use VSCode like a WYSIWYG md-editor like [typora](https://typora.io/) but with all the benefits of using your daily edtior. This should also be interesting for programmers - at least on hackernews typora is regularly praised as the best markdown editor (see e.g. [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15494655))

I didn't see an addon for this. Something related was discussed about two years ago in [issue 7689](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7689) - but this only concerns a mini preview in the gutter or if you move the mouse over a link. For this there is already the add-on [Image preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview).

Comment: Filed [FR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97953)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible as of VS Code 1.29. The VS Code api does not provide a way to insert custom elements like images into the editor.

The two closest existing APIs:

- The code lens api: `CodeLensProvider`. These allow you to insert additional clickable commands into an editor (such as displaying a reference count above a function) but these can only be text buttons
- The hover api: `HoverProvider`. Hovers can contain images since they display markdown content. However they are only displayed when the user hovers over them